# Nodes stack on top of each other vis.js network

Tags: vis.js, vis.js-network

When my page loads all of the nodes in my vis.js network are on top of each other.
How can I make it so that when the page is loaded the network looks like its supposed to...?

This is what it looks like now:

[image]

And I want it to look like this:
[image]

So I want space between the nodes automatically.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the difference between your data layout and the basic example in https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/?

Comment: @Franck I basicly don't have anything different than the basic layout in the examples. I fill the nodes and edges with data from apiresponses. I have tried adjusting the options with a number of things but it stays like this... The hierarchical option isn't what I want since I want to be able to move the nodes freely.

Comment: Adding additional edges breaks the hierarchical structure and the layout in the fiddle is still fine. Unfortunately, I can't reproduce your problem.